# How to split a table's data into two sets based on a column value with Hibnernate mappings?

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose there are three tables:

```
Table A (ID, NAME)
Table B (ID, NAME)
Table A-B (A_ID, B_ID, Boolean_Property)
```

and Table A and B are modeled by classes A and B as follows:

```
public class A {
    private long id;
    private String name;

    // All the B's that belong to A where the boolean property is True
    Set<B> trueBSet;

    // All the B's that belong to A where the boolean property is False
    Set<B> falseBSet;
}

public class B {
    private long id;
    private String name;
}
```

How would I model this using Hibernate? I would like to be able to do the following, but it appears that discriminator column values don't exist for set attributes:

```
<class name="A" table="A">
    <id name="id" column="ID">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="name" column="NAME" />

    <set name="trueB" table="A-B">
        <key column="A_ID"/>
        <many-to-many column="B_ID" class="B"/>
        <discriminator column="Boolean_Property" value="True" />
    </set>

    <set name="falseB" table="A-B">
        <key column="A_ID"/>
        <many-to-many column="B_ID" class="B"/>
        <discriminator column="Boolean_Property" value="False" />
    </set>
</class>
```

Comment: Pretty much an exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761901/multiple-manytomany-sets-from-one-join-table

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can apply where clause in  set tag. Hibernate document state as follows in following link
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html

where (optional): specifies an arbitrary SQL WHERE condition that is used when retrieving or removing the collection. This is useful if the collection needs to contain only a subset of the available data.

Comment: `where` works for read-only collections or when you're **really** dealing with a subset of data (and can therefore default missing columns on insert). It won't help with maintaining two separate collections based off the same table

Answer (score 0):

as @ChssPly76 said this is a duplicate of
[Multiple @ManyToMany sets from one join table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761901/multiple-manytomany-sets-from-one-join-table)

The solutions there suggest to use a view as Join-Column and plain SQL for CRUD operations.

This Answer is marked community wiki so if anyone else wants this question to leave the 'unanswered' section may freely upvote it.